# VSCode and flutter, how to connect multiple devices?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I am using Visual Studio Code on macOS for developing Flutter apps.

I can select a single device in the bottom-left of VSC. I can also run on multiple devices using `flutter run -d all`. I am wondering how I can run on multiple devices using the debug console in VSC. Or, at the very least, debug one device but show updates on all.

Thank you

Answer (score 34):

If you're on recent versions of Flutter and the Dart/Flutter extensions (Dec 2019 onwards) this is now supported using VS Code's compound launch configurations.

Your `.vscode/launch.json` should contain an entry for each device, along with its `deviceId` (this is the ID you would pass to `flutter run -d xxx`):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Current Device",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Android",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "android"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "iphone"
        },
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "All Devices",
            "configurations": ["Android", "iPhone"],
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code.

Comment: Review your answer. As of now, it is supported

Comment: Nice reference. The one thing missing from that article is how to find your `deviceId` (say if you have to set a new one up later) --- From a terminal, run `flutter devices`. The first column is the device's name; the second is the `deviceId`. This helped me find and set my Android `deviceId`, and launch my Android emulator. However, the `deviceId` for the `iPhone` in the `configurations` list (which was set when `launch.json` was created) doesn't match the `deviceId` in the `flutter devices` results, but... the iPhone emulator still works, and comes up right alongside the Android emulator.

Answer (score 6):

How about this one, it worked for me

```
flutter run -d all
```

Answer (score 3):

well you can run only two devices or two virtual machine at the same time
one using command `flutter run -d <put the id of the device>`

and the other using f5 and choose the other device

Comment: No, you can actually run more than two. I have 2 emulator and a device running currently.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter 1.12 support multi device debugging in VS Code
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code

Answer (score 2):

If you have different flavors, you can configure your launch.json config as follows.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
      // config "Run Dev Android" and "Run Dev Iphone" will be user for multiple debuging,
    {
        "name": "Run Dev Android",
        "request": "launch",
        "deviceId": "SM",
        "type": "dart",
         "program": "lib/app/flavors/main_development.dart",
         "flutterMode": "debug",
         "args": [
             "--flavor", "development",
         ]
       
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Dev Iphone",
        "flutterMode": "debug",
        "deviceId": "Iphone",
         "program": "lib/app/flavors/main_development.dart",
         "type": "dart",
         "args": [
             "--flavor", "development",
         ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Dev",
        "program": "lib/app/flavors/main_development.dart",
        "flutterMode": "debug",
        "deviceId": "Android",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": [
            "--flavor", "development",
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Stage",
        "program": "lib/app/flavors/main_staging.dart",
        "flutterMode": "debug",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": [
            "--flavor", "staging"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Prod",
        "program": "lib/app/flavors/main_development.dart",
        "flutterMode": "release",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": [
            "--flavor", "production"
        ]
    },
],
"compounds": [{
        "name": "All Devices",
        "configurations": ["Run Dev Android", "Run Dev Iphone"],
       
    }]

}
```

[image]

Now you can select the `All Device` and hit run.