# Running flutter apps on multiple simulators

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app that is about 70 percent complete.  I want to run it on multiple simulators because one of the functionalities is sending data between phones.  My question is, can I do this?   I am using mostly android but would like the app to be cross-platform.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal, launch the emulators you want:

```
flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>
```

*(to get the emulators IDs, run `flutter emulator`, and they'll be listed on the left hand side)*

then from the terminal:

```
flutter run -d all
```

This command will run your app in all the running emulators. To use Hot Reload, just type 'r' in the terminal (flutter will show you the commands that you need).

Comment: Thank you @OsaXma!   Much appreciated!

Comment: Any way of doing this on VSCode?

Comment: @VCezar check this answer here _[VSCode and flutter, how to connect multiple devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889130/10976714)_